# Using MouseEnter/MouseLeave events with ContextMenus

Tags: c#, wpf, events, contextmenu, mouseenter

I have a `ContextMenu` on a `Button` that I'd like to open on a `MouseEnter` event, instead of on the default right-click event.  Here's my XAML:

```
<Button Content="Button" MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            .... context menu items ....
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

And the associated event handlers:

```
private void Button_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{  
    backButtonContextMenu.Placement = PlacementMode.Bottom;
    backButtonContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    Console.WriteLine("MouseEnter called");
}

private void Button_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{  
    backButtonContextMenu.IsOpen = false;
    Console.WriteLine("MouseLeave called");
}
```

Pretty straight forward.  Unfortunately, while hovering over the button, these two methods get called infinitely, alternating back and forth.  Here's an example of the output in my console:

```
MouseEnter called
MouseLeave called
MouseEnter called
MouseLeave called
MouseEnter called
MouseLeave called
MouseEnter called
MouseLeave called
  ... etc. ...
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with the ContextMenu stealing the focus when it's open, or perhaps laying down some kind of invisible "helper" backdrop to detect when it needs to be closed.  Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior, and is there a way to avoid it? It's a pretty simple effect, from a UI standpoint.

Comment: On mouseEnter you should check whether ContextMenu is open or not. You should not open it again if it is open already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's going into a cycle cos when the `ContextMenu` is invoked the `Button` looses mouse over which then closes the `ContextMenu` and now the mouse over again returns to the `Button` and you got your loop.

you could just go:

```
private void Button_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (backButtonContextMenu.IsMouseOver)
    return;
  backButtonContextMenu.IsOpen = false;
  Debug.WriteLine("MouseLeave called");
}
```

however now you got the issue of having to close the menu at another moment.

In such cases when I'd need a menu like a `ContextMenu` but not in it's default behavior, I'd tend to go for a `Popup`.

say the same thing with a `Popup`:

```
<StackPanel>
  <Button x:Name="button"
          Content="Button" />
  <Button x:Name="button2"
          Content="Button 2" />
  <Popup Placement="Right"
          PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=button}">
    <Menu>
      <MenuItem Header="AAA" />
    </Menu>
    <Popup.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
        <Setter Property="IsOpen"
                Value="True" />
        <Style.Triggers>
          <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                            Path=PlacementTarget.IsMouseOver}"
                          Value="False" />
              <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                            Path=IsMouseOver}"
                          Value="False" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="IsOpen"
                    Value="False" />
          </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </Popup.Style>
  </Popup>
</StackPanel>
```

You can ofc tweak it's conditions to what you need.

Comment: Thanks, I did end up switching to a `Popup`.  Much easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem recently where I needed a menu to open and close when the mouse was over the button. Viv's excellent answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17453601/3403999) worked with one minor caveat: I noticed a flicker effect when the mouse would transition from the button to the popup (and vice versa). Basically the popup was closing and reopening in that fraction of a second. I initially tried using the HorizontalOffset property to cause the popup to overlap, but the flicker remained.

My ultimate solution was to add Enter/Exit actions with a really basic storyboard that I thought I'd share in case anyone one else saw Viv's answer and was trying to figure out how to prevent the flicker:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="button"
            Content="Button" />
    <Button x:Name="button2"
            Content="Button 2" />
    <Popup Placement="Right"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=button}">
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="AAA" />
        </Menu>
        <Popup.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
                <Setter Property="IsOpen"
                        Value="True" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                                         Path=PlacementTarget.IsMouseOver}"
                                       Value="False" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                                         Path=IsMouseOver}"
                                       Value="False" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="HidePopupStoryboard">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen"
                                                                    Duration="0:0:0.1">
                                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="100%"
                                                                 Value="False" />
                                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="HidePopupStoryboard" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Popup.Style>
    </Popup>
</StackPanel>
```

You can increase the duration to make it linger open for a short bit, but even 1/10th of a second delay was enough to prevent the flickering for me. You could also even thrown in a double animation and have it fade out / in instead of just outright open / close.